# String Array's first item is always blank when using scanner input

Tags: java, arrays, string

My string array's first element is always blank for some reason and I cannot seem to figure out the error in my array input and display code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Source {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {      
    int i=0,size=0,j=0,flag1=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Size");
    if(in.hasNextLine()){
        size = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Input Elements");
    String[] input = new String[size];      
    i=0;
    String blank = in.nextLine();
    while(i<size){          
        if(in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("i ="+i);            
        input[i]=in.nextLine();
        i++;
        }           
    } 
    i=0;
    System.out.println("Input Array is");
    while(i<size){          
        System.out.println("Input"+i+"= "+input[i]);
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

The gives me the following output in the terminal
[image: Terminal Output]

What do I seem to be doing incorrectly ?
Would love to understand what is my error is here.

Comment: A `For-Loop` would probably serve you better in a couple of these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `System.out.println("i ="+i);` outside of `if`.

```java
while(i<size){ 
    System.out.println("i ="+i); 
    if(in.hasNextLine()) {
        input[i]=in.nextLine();
        i++;
    }           
}
```

Also, `in.nextLine();` is enough to skip newline. No need to store it `String blank = in.nextLine();`.
Scanner skipping `nextLine()` is taken care of by `String blank = in.nextLine();`, but yet it still takes one extra blank. 
The reason is `if(in.hasNextLine())`, if there's no input given it'll be stuck there and won't print the `i=0`, and I assume you have press `enter` which makes the condition true and prints `i=0` but that `enter` blank new line is considered as input for `i=0`. Then followed by input `string1` which is input for `i=1` and so on.

Comment: Ah I see,thank you ! is there a specific reason the scanner takes one extra blank line as input ?
afaik shouldn't it just take the next string input for `input[0]` ?

Comment: @udbhav for question in previous comment see [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/16320675)

Comment: @udbhavshrivastava sorry for the late reply, I've added an explanation in the answer. you can check.